# JSF2.2: Get result of action (no reload)

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, action, jsf-2.2

First of all, I'm new to JSF. Is it possible to get the result of an action at the xhtml page?

So, let me explain this by an little example: The situation is that the dialog below is allready opend.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dialog" modal=true>
  <h:outputLabel for="inTxt" value="Seats:" />
  <h:inputText id="inTxt" value="#{model.seats}" />
  <p:commandButton value="Save" 
     action="#{model.saveAction()}"
     oncomplete="PF('dialog').hide();"/>
</p:dialog>
```

(model is the backBean)

```
public Class Model {
  private int seats;
  ...
  public String saveAction() {
    if(seats == 10) {
      return "success"
    } else {
      return "failure"
    }        
  }
  // Getter & Setter
}
```

In case of saveAction() returns "failure" the dialog shouldn't closed. This all should happen without reloading the page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible using ajax. first of all the method should be void, and the attribute of the commandButton should be actionListener instead of action. This is the code for the commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" 
     actionListener="#{model.saveAction}" />
```

In case of success, you will have to programmatically redirect. You can use this code:

```
FacesContext context = FaccesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, null, "/success?faces-redirect=true");
```

In case of failure, use this code to close the dialog from the managed bean:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dialog.hide()");
```

In primefaces showcase there is a demo with something similar. Instead of closing the dialog from the managed bean, the send a parameter back to the page and close the dialog in a javascript method. This is the [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf)

Comment: The example from Primefaces is nice. So its easy to lock the page, if the server need some time to work.